# Raphaël: edit the style of a set of paths grouped together

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael

I'm making a dynamic map using Raphaël. I have various paths (let's say a path for each country), and I'm using a script similar to the demo found in this page:
http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/australia.html, in order to change dinamically the cursor, the colors and the visibility od the callout div.

However, some countries are made of different paths, and I need to group them under a single tag (because otherwise there would be conflicts with tags, and not all of the paths would be affected). I merged them in a single path using a set:

```
var group1 = R.set();
group1.push(path1);
group1.push(path2);
group1.attr({fill: 'red'});
```

and the paths are plotted correctly, with the proper colors; however, when I try to edit the style of the merged path, using for example this command:

```
st[0].style.cursor = "pointer";
```

I get the following error

```
st[0].style is undefined
```

while it worked fine when using directly a path and not a set...

How can I edit the style of the grouped paths?

Answer (score 0):

Raphaël instances don't have a `style` method, perhaps you were using the node. This should work...

```
st[0].node.style.cursor = "pointer";
```

Though the *raphael* way of doing this would be:

```
st[0].attr("cursor", "pointer");
```

Comment: I can't get it work in that way... 
Is it there a way to directly draw two separate paths under one single R.path? I tried combining in a single line, for example:
`R.path(m 458,433 ...... 0.91,0.55 z m 478,460 ..... 0.25, -0.51 z);`
But that didn't work...

Comment: Ah, I see, try renaming the second `m` to uppercase `M` and let me know how it goes.

Comment: This is what I get renaming the second `m` to `M` (I also tryed with the second `z` to `Z`, same result):
http://oi68.tinypic.com/aky6fa.jpg

Comment: Leaving the lowercase m, it seems like the second path is being ignored... Maybe something is wrong with the syntax, or there is another way to achieve that.

Comment: I got it!!!
Using the absolute reference system couldn't work, since the first sub-path was plotted with a relative reference system.
The solution was moving by a difference between the 2 starting points:
(m 478,460) − (m 458,433)  -----> the second path had to start with `m 20, 27` and not with `m 478,460`.